# C Program Incorrect Output

Tags: c, output, off-by-one

I am currently writing a program that is supposed to receive input from a text file and output statistics about the text such as the number of letters, size of words and how often they occur, and how many times each word occurs. However, every time I run the program, the wordLengthAnalysis does not produce the correct output. The other two run perfectly. Here is some sample text (The number represents how many lines are supposed to be read):

1
Hello my name is Bob
 
I live in Canada

Usually it is only off by one number. What should I do to correct my issue? I am very new to programming so I'm sure it is something basic.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_WORD_LENGTH 20
#define MAX_LINES 10
#define MAX_LINE_LENGTH 80

void letterAnalysis(char text[][MAX_LINE_LENGTH], int lineTotal);
int wordLengthAnalysis(char text[][MAX_LINE_LENGTH], int lineTotal, int wordLength);
void wordAnalysis(char text[][MAX_LINE_LENGTH], int lineTotal);


int main (void){

    int lineTotal, wordSize;

    scanf("%d\n", &lineTotal);
    char text[lineTotal][MAX_LINE_LENGTH];

    for(int i = 0; i < lineTotal; i++){
        gets(text[i]);
    }

    printf("\n***Letter count analysis***\n");
    letterAnalysis(text, lineTotal);

    printf("\n***Word length analysis***\n");
    for (int i = 1; i < 21; i++){
        wordSize = wordLengthAnalysis(text, lineTotal, i);
        if (wordSize == 1){
            printf("\n%-2d\tword of length %d", wordSize, i);
        }
        else if (wordSize == 0){}
        else{
            printf("\n%-2d\twords of length %d", wordSize, i);
        }
    }

    printf("\n\n***Word analysis***\n");
    wordAnalysis(text, lineTotal);

    return 0;

}

void letterAnalysis(char text[][MAX_LINE_LENGTH], int lineTotal){

    int alphabet[26] = {0};

    for (int i = 0; i < lineTotal; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < MAX_LINE_LENGTH; j++){
            switch(text[i][j]){
                case 'A': case 'a':
                alphabet[0]++;
                break;
                case 'B': case 'b':
                alphabet[1]++;
                break;
                case 'C': case 'c':
                alphabet[2]++;
                break;
                case 'D': case 'd':
                alphabet[3]++;
                break;
                case 'E': case 'e':
                alphabet[4]++;
                break;
                case 'F': case 'f':
                alphabet[5]++;
                break;
                case 'G': case 'g':
                alphabet[6]++;
                break;
                case 'H': case 'h':
                alphabet[7]++;
                break;
                case 'I': case 'i':
                alphabet[8]++;
                break;
                case 'J': case 'j':
                alphabet[9]++;
                break;
                case 'K': case 'k':
                alphabet[10]++;
                break;
                case 'L': case 'l':
                alphabet[11]++;
                break;
                case 'M': case 'm':
                alphabet[12]++;
                break;
                case 'N': case 'n':
                alphabet[13]++;
                break;
                case 'O': case 'o':
                alphabet[14]++;
                break;
                case 'P': case 'p':
                alphabet[15]++;
                break;
                case 'Q': case 'q':
                alphabet[16]++;
                break;
                case 'R': case 'r':
                alphabet[17]++;
                break;
                case 'S': case 's':
                alphabet[18]++;
                break;
                case 'T': case 't':
                alphabet[19]++;
                break;
                case 'U': case 'u':
                alphabet[20]++;
                break;
                case 'V': case 'v':
                alphabet[21]++;
                break;
                case 'W': case 'w':
                alphabet[22]++;
                break;
                case 'X': case 'x':
                alphabet[23]++;
                break;
                case 'Y': case 'y':
                alphabet[24]++;
                break;
                case 'Z': case 'z':
                alphabet[25]++;
                default: break;
            }       
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i <= 25; i++){
        printf("%c: \t%d\n", ('a' + i), alphabet[i]);;
    }
}

int wordLengthAnalysis(char text[][MAX_LINE_LENGTH], int lineTotal, int wordLength){

    int sentenceLength;
    int counter, wordSize = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < lineTotal; i++){
        sentenceLength = strlen(&text[i][0]);
        for(int j = 0; j < sentenceLength; j++){
            if(text[i][j] == ' '){
                if(counter == wordLength){
                    wordSize++;
                    counter = 0;
                }
                else{
                counter = 0;
                }
            }
            else{
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }

    return wordSize;
}

void wordAnalysis(char text[][MAX_LINE_LENGTH], int lineTotal){

    char maxWords[800];
    char word[MAX_LINE_LENGTH], word2[MAX_WORD_LENGTH], *ptrText, *ptrTextCounter;
    int counter, textCounter = 0;
    int sentenceLength, wordTracker;
    int lineFlag;

    for(int i = 0; i < lineTotal; i++){
        ptrText = &text[i][0];
        sentenceLength = strlen(ptrText);
        counter = 0;

        for (int j = 0; j < sentenceLength + 1; j++){
            wordTracker = 1;

            if (text[i][j] == ' ' ){
                if (counter != 0){
                    sprintf(word, "%.*s", counter, ptrText);
                    ptrTextCounter = &text[i][j+1];
                    lineFlag = j;

                if(strstr(maxWords, word) == NULL){
                    for (int k = i; k < lineTotal; k++){
                        textCounter = 0;

                        if (lineFlag == j){
                            ptrTextCounter = &text[i][j+1];
                        }
                        else{
                            lineFlag = 0;
                            ptrTextCounter = &text[i][j+1];
                        }

                        for ( ; lineFlag < sentenceLength; lineFlag++){
                            if(text[k][lineFlag] == ' '){
                                if (textCounter != 0){
                                    if(textCounter == counter){
                                        sprintf(word2, "%.*s", textCounter, ptrTextCounter);
                                            if(strcmp(word, word2) == 0){
                                                wordTracker++;
                                            }
                                    }
                                    ptrTextCounter = &text[k][lineFlag + 1];
                                    textCounter = 0;
                                }
                                else{
                                    ptrTextCounter = &text[k][lineFlag+1];
                                }
                            }
                            else{
                                textCounter++;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if(wordTracker == 1){
                        printf("\n\"%.*s\"\t\tappeared %d time", counter, ptrText, wordTracker);
                    }
                    else{
                        printf("\n\"%.*s\"\t\tappeared %d times", counter, ptrText, wordTracker);
                    }
                }


                strcat(maxWords, word);
                    ptrText = &text[i][j+1];
                    counter = 0;
                }
                else{
                    ptrText = &text[i][j+1];
                }
            }
            else{
                counter++;
            }
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: when it works I suggest codereview. Your switch/case code is just horrible: `alphabet[toupper(text[i][j])-'A']++;` does the same as your 100 lines case.

Comment: that would help to shorten your code: imagine people trying to understand your big wall of code. Who wants to do that?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre That wouldn't handle `case 'a'`

Comment: @CoolGuy `toupper` does that!

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Ah, sorry. I missed that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you need to set counter to 0 at the start of every line.

```
for(int i = 0; i < lineTotal; i++){
    sentenceLength = strlen(&text[i][0]);
    counter = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j < sentenceLength; j++){
```

You also need to check if the counter is equal at the end of each line.

```
for(int j = 0; j < sentenceLength; j++){
    if(text[i][j] == ' '){
        if(counter == wordLength){
            wordSize++;
            counter = 0;
        }
            else{
            counter = 0;
        }
    }
    else{
        counter++;
    }
}
if(counter == wordLength){
    wordSize++;
    counter = 0;
}
```

Hope this helps!